# AJAX PHP form can't resend data / always stops at phone num. field

Tags: html, ajax, forms, contacts

I'm trying to make a simple contact form for my website, so I bought one from Code Canyon. After not receiving slow and scarce help from the author, I'm asking you guys for help.

Basically it's a very simple contact form but I'm not too good with coding so it bothers me regardless. This is the HTML code;

```
<div id="contact" class="clearfix"><!-- contact -->

<h1><img name="logo" src="" width="300" height="50" alt="" style="background-color: #3366FF" /></h1><p class="txn">Lorem ipsum dim sum sum.</p>  

        <div id="message"></div>
        
        <form method="post" action="contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
        
        <fieldset>
                
        <legend>Please fill in the following form to contact us</legend>
    
        <label for=name accesskey=U><span class="required">*</span> Your Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" value="" /> 
    
        <br />
        <label for=email accesskey=E><span class="required">*</span> Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" value="" />
    
        <br />
        <label for=phone accesskey=P><span class="required">*</span> Phone</label>
        <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="30" value="" />
    
        <br />
        <label for=subject accesskey=S>Subject</label>
        <select name="subject" type="text" id="subject">
          <option value="Support">Support</option>
          <option value="a Sale">Sales</option>
          <option value="a Bug fix">Report a bug</option>
        </select>
    
        <br />
        <label for=comments accesskey=C><span class="required">*</span> Your comments</label>
        <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="3"  id="comments" style="width: 350px;"></textarea>
                        
        <p><span class="required">*</span> Are you human?</p>
                
        <label for=verify accesskey=V>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3 + 1 =</label>
        <input name="verify" type="text" id="verify" size="4" value="" style="width: 30px;" /><br /><br />
    
        <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        
        </fieldset>
    
        </form>
```

The JavaScript file I was given in the template...practically unchanged

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$('#contactform').submit(function(){

    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    
    $("#message").slideUp(450,function() {
    $('#message').hide();
    
    $('#submit')
        .after('<img src="assets/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />')
        .attr('disabled','disabled');
    
    $.post(action, { 
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        phone: $('#telephone').val(),
        subject: $('#enquiry').val(),
        comments: $('#message').val(),
    },
        function(data){
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
            $('#message').slideDown('fast');
            $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
            $('#contactform #submit').attr('disabled',''); 
            if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');
            
        }
    );
    
    });
    
    return false; 

    });

    });
```

And then there is the contact-php file I got

```
<?php
```

if(!$_POST) exit;

```
    $name     = $_POST['name'];
    $email    = $_POST['email'];
    $phone   = $_POST['phone'];
    $subject  = $_POST['subject'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];
    $verify   = $_POST['verify'];

    if(trim($name) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter your name.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(trim($email) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(trim($phone) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid phone number.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(!is_numeric($phone)) {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Phone number can only contain digits.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(!isEmail($email)) {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
        exit();
    }
    
    if(trim($subject) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a subject.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(trim($comments) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter your message.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(trim($verify) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter the verification number.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(trim($verify) != '4') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! The verification number you entered is incorrect.</div>';
        exit();  
    }
    
    if($error == '') {
    
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $comments = stripslashes($comments);
        }


     // Configuration option.
     // Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
     // Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";
     
     //$address = "example@themeforest.net";
     $address = "mylerworks@gmail.com";


     // Configuration option.
     // i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."
     
     // Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

     $e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';


     // Configuration option.
     // You can change this if you feel that you need to.
     // Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.
                
     $e_body = "You have been contacted by $name with regards to $subject, their additional message is as follows.\r\n\n";
     $e_content = "\"$comments\"\r\n\n";
     $e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email or via phone $phone";
                
     $msg = $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply;

     if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n")) {


     // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.
    
     echo "<fieldset>";         
     echo "<div id='success_page'>";
     echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
     echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
     echo "</div>";
     echo "</fieldset>";
             
     } else {
     
     echo 'ERROR!';
     
     }
                  
}

     function isEmail($email) { // Email address verification, do not edit.

     return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
```

}
?>

Problem is: let's say I fill up the form but forget to put my name in. The form will notify me I forgot it but I will not be able to post it, I will need to refresh the page. Also, it keeps giving me the "please enter a valid phone number" error even when I fill the form completely.

So how do I get it to work?

In case I didn't post something correctly here, check how the form looks here - [You can view the form here](http://leosmedia.com/test/test.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your submit button is disabled after posting data . That is why you are not able to re-post it

$('#contactform #submit').attr('disabled','');

1. Use correct id of input field.

phone: $('#telephone').val(),

this will be always null as there is no component with this id

Comment: Thanks! I've changed the attr of submit button to enabled. But now I get the Please enter a subject error?

Answer (score 0):

Its same kind of error. There is no element with id enquiry or message.

subject: $('#enquiry').val(),
comments: $('#message').val(),

Please be sure about name and id of your html components while retrieving values

Thanks